# HTML5 datetime component is not working in browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I worte simple html5 input type 'datetime" .

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input type="datetime" width="30px">
</body>
</html>
```

The Ran the above code in IE(Edge). output is dispalying as simple test input. My guess, this datetime component is removed in all browsers. Can you please suggest me any way to implement this component.

Comment: See the Browser Compatibility table in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime

Comment: Current, you would have to build the element or elements which render the required output at browsers where `<input type="datetime">` is not supported. You should be be able to achieve this using `shadowDOM` or a combination of several supported `<input>` elements

Answer (score 2):

correct code is : (replace datetime with date)

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
   <input type="date" width="30px">
 </body>
</html>
```

It works well with Edge, chrome etc.

Comment: Except that's not what the question is about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you may consider to use input type datetime-local: this works only in edge and chrome but not in all browsers.

An alternative can be considered: a jquery ui plugin or boostrap according to which one is the right approach for you.

You may use [jQuery-Timepicker-Addon](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon) like in the following snippet:

```js
$('#basic_example_3').datetimepicker({
  timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/master/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/master/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>


<input id="basic_example_3" type="text">
```

If, instead, you can use boostrap you may use [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) like in the following snippet:

```js
$('#appointment_end_datetime').datetimepicker({
  format: "Y-M-d H:mm",
  sideBySide: true
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='appointment_end_datetime'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```